# Access to data variable in mounted returns undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to build a simple chat based on Vue.js and socket.io. I have a normal get call to get all pevious messages, this one works fine and the view gets updated.

But when I try to update messages from within the socket.io block, I get an error message saying `this.messages is undefined`. I lookde with the vue debugger, the new message is not pushed.

Is this a problem with the scope of this?

Here is my Chat.vue

```js
<template>
    <div class="chat">
        <h1>Chat</h1>
        <ul id="messages" class="messages">
            <li v-for="message in messages" v-bind:key="message.timestamp">
                {{ message.timestamp }}: {{ message.text }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    import axios from "axios";
    import io from 'socket.io-client';

    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                messages: [{
                    timestamp: null,
                    message: ""
                }]
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            this.fetch();
            let socket = io();
            socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
                // This fails with the error message
                this.messages.push(JSON.parse(msg));
            });
        },
        methods: {
            fetch() {

                axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/messages').then((response) => {
                    response = JSON.parse(response.data);
                    // This works without a problem
                    this.messages = response;
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
    .messages {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: use an arrow function like you did with axios callback

Comment: A that explains why the axos call worked :) thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling a function (non vue function) the scope of `this` is changed.

```
socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
   // This fails with the error message
   this.messages.push(JSON.parse(msg));
});
```

So in this case `this` is not bound to you're vue context any more and `this.messages` will be `undefined`. So you have to bind `this` to the method.

In the old fashion way you could use a `function() {}.bind(this)` but since we currently have ES6 we don't use this anymore. we use an arrow function. Full details about the arrow functions: (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp)

```
socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
   // This fails with the error message
   this.messages.push(JSON.parse(msg));
});
```